Can we please undelete a question?
Here is my question asked 10 years ago: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/how-belief-in-own-specialness-called

How belief in own specialness called?
Solipsism is a belief that nothing exists outside one's mind.

I wonder how called a belief that oneself has special properties compared to other people, obey different physical laws etc. while
admitting their existence?

How called a position that one's own mind is the only existing mind, together with the belief in the existence of the physical
(external) world (as opposed to solopsism's position that all the
world exists in the one's own mind)?



In my view, this is a legit question about terminology, how this special form of weak solipsism is called.
But the question was deleted with arguments that it is not about philosophy but rather about psychology or even mental disorder.

as for the content of the question itself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%ABniby%C5%8D may be informative, and from there follow the "see also" section

@ac15 I am banned from asking questions for 10 years now, because at the time questions were often deleted for ridiculous reasons as "not about philosophy"
